# Boundary condition of graviton fluctuations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, boundary-conditions

When computing Euclidean gravitational path integral, one expands around a saddle point, and naturally there is a classical part and a one-loop part (and more). In particular, the one-loop part can be thought as integrating over all fluctuations $$g_{\mu\nu}'=g^{(0)}_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu}$$ decomposed into the eigentensors of the kinetic operator of the graviton in the saddle point background:  $\delta g_{\mu\nu}=\sum c_{\lambda}h_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$. To make the discussion concrete let us restrict the classical background to be Euclidean AdS$_4$.

My question is whether the fluctuations have to respect the symmetries of the classical saddle point, which, in this case means $g'_{\mu\nu}$ preserves all the AdS$_4$ killing vectors at $\rho \to \infty $, where $\rho$ is the radial coordinate. If that is not the case, the bulk graviton fluctuation seems to change the boundary geometry.